# Why does this MySQL query take forever to run?

Tags: php, mysql

Table1 is only 1mb and table2 is 10mb but the query takes at least 30 seconds to load. Is it because of the SUM and COUNT functions?

```
$index = mysql_query("CREATE index table1_timestamp on table1(timestamp)");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT
    table1.user_id,
    table1.timestamp,
    COUNT(DISTINCT table1.call_id) as calls,
    SUM(table2.recording_file_duration) / 60 as minutes
FROM
    table1
JOIN table2 ON
    table1.call_id = table2.id
WHERE
    table1.user_id = '244'
    AND
    table1.timestamp >= '2013-07-01' and table1.timestamp < '2013-08-01'
GROUP BY
    table1.user_id,
    DAY(table1.timestamp)
ORDER BY
    table1.timestamp DESC");
```

EDIT: I just checked and table 2 has 300,000 rows. Is that why?

Comment: The size in MB isn't as important as the number of records...

Comment: Do I read create index before each select query?

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` before your `SELECT` to see what MySQL is doing.  That might help debug.  `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...`

Comment: Are you using indexed columns for your join?

Comment: First, fix ambiguity by always qualifying tableAlias.ColumnName.  Where is User_ID from and TimeStamp columns associated.  I would have an index on ( user_id, timestamp, recording_file_duration ), and the calls table a minimum index of the (id) column... but unsure of first index due to ambiguity.

Comment: You're recreating the index every time you call the page?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how indexes work.

Comment: MySQL would complain if there were actual ambiguity in the query.  It would help clarify the schema for us humans, though.

Comment: `// $index = mysql_query("CREATE index call_audit_table_timestamp on call_audit_table(timestamp)");` will probably fix your issue(s)

Comment: @user802519: Well...indexes are persistent, for starters.  You create them around the same time you're creating tables and such.  (You can create them later if you want, but you only need to do it once -- not once per query, or anything like that.  I'm semi surprised MySQL lets you do this without dropping the previously created index.)

Comment: What is `table2` if your are doing a JOIN on `calls`?

Comment: Sorry table2 used to be calls but i tried to make it more clear and missed one

Comment: use EXPLAIN and tell us what the result is.

Comment: and u shouldn't use mysql_* extensions anymore. use PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index that your `WHERE` clause can utilize for `table1`. Also, add an index that the `JOIN` can use for `table2`.

Add the following indexes:

```
table1(user_id, timestamp) // Order is important here, ranges go last
table2(id)
```

Of course, if `table2.id` is your primary key, you don't need to add that index.

To improve the results even more, you could add covering indexes:

```
table1(user_id, timestamp, call_id)
table2(id, recording_file_duration)
```

If you are using InnoDB and any of those columns are primary keys, remove them from the index.